# Server is restarted after an axios request with express

Tags: javascript

My problem is, My project's server is restarted After an axios request with express.
I can see http://localhost:3000/__webpack_hmr 200 OK in console of chrome.

when I add vocabulary to data or remove that, server is restarted.
This is the vue client code. ([github link to file](https://github.com/devgaram/nuxt-express/blob/master/nuxt-express/pages/index.vue))

```
methods: {
    addVocabulary () {
      var vm = this
      this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
        if (result) {
          axios.post('/api/vc/add', {
            vocabulary: this.vocabulary
          }).then(function (response) {
            vm.vocabularies = response.data
          }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
          })
          this.vocabulary = ''
        } else {
          console.log('Not valid')
        }
      })
    },
    remove (id) {
      var vm = this
      axios({
        method: 'delete',
        url: '/api/vc/remove',
        data: {id: id},
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
      }).then(function (response) {
        vm.vocabularies = response.data
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
  }
```

And this is the server side code.[link to file](https://github.com/devgaram/nuxt-express/blob/master/nuxt-express/server/api/vocabularies.js)

```
router.post('/vc/add', function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)
  let vocabulary = req.body.vocabulary
  let objVocabulary = {}
  objVocabulary.id = 10
  objVocabulary.content = vocabulary
  vocabularies.push(objVocabulary)

  fse.outputJson(file, vocabularies, err=>{
    console.log(err);
    fse.readJson(file, (err, data) =>{
        res.json(data);
    })
  })
})

/* DELETE remove voca */
router.delete('/vc/remove', (req, res, next) =>{
  if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)
  let id = req.body.id
  var index = vocabularies.findIndex(voca => voca.id === id);
  vocabularies.splice(index,1);

  fse.outputJson(file, vocabularies, err=>{
    console.log(err);
    fse.readJson(file, (err, data) =>{
        res.json(data);
    })
  })

})
```

Here's my project link to [github](https://github.com/devgaram/nuxt-express/tree/master/nuxt-express),
I don't know why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are using `backpack`.

> Their documentation quotes: Live reload (on saves, add/delete file, etc.)

So, if you the JSON file you are manipulating in your server code is in a folder watched by backpack, hot module reload will kick in and restart the server.

Solution: Move the json to some other directory --> your database shouldn't be part of your source code anyways.

Comment: awesome! glad I could help. Also, I may say, welcome to SO! If this helped do you mind upvoting and accepting it. It will help others facing the same problem as you did. You can learn more about it in our help center guide: [when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)